# Google Map - Do not display until tilt loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Currently when I load a map with satellite imagery, it will quickly flash the overhead view and then load the 45 degree tilt version. How can I prevent the map from displaying until the tilt has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by using a `setTimeout` directly after my map object is created which displays then displays the element.

Answer (score 0):

so what is probably happening is it is loading into the 3d model of the map, what I would recommend trying is changing the zoom setting on the map and seeing if that does make a difference.

Comment: Unfortunately the zoom setting I have is the one that I want to keep